# How to make MacOS app url request to text field?

Tags: swift, macos, button, text, urlrequest

I need to make an app on MacOS with a single button and a single text field, so when I press the button , particular data (mySubstring) from internet will appear in text box. I've tried to do that in Swift Playground , it works fine and here is the code:

```
import Foundation



var info: String = ""
let mySubstring = ""
let myString = String(mySubstring)


var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=1502026&appid=df10ddc41c923a4f0e93ffc67631f0c5")!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
{ data, response, error in

info = String(decoding: data!, as: UTF8.self)

    let index = info.index(info.startIndex, offsetBy: 16)
    let endindex = info.index(info.startIndex, offsetBy: 22)
    let mySubstring = info[index...endindex]
 

print(mySubstring)
    
}


task.resume()
```

but when I try to gather it all to a Project. I need to do in App exactly what I wrote, thereafter I will extend my tasks.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's not clear what exactly is your question/problem here. You say that your code works in Playground, it's great. Then you need to create a macOS app and... what?

Comment: show us the code you have in your `App` and where it does not work, including the error you get. PS: do **not** show your secret `appid`, remove it.

Comment: Have you done the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/  If not, do it, that will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, your code shows very clearly that you have to learn the basics at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Then you have to do the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

Without knowing the basics you are not going to understand the answers from SO.

Here is some example code to get you going:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var mySubstring = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Testing this")
            HStack {
                Button(action: { loadData() }) {
                    Text("Push me")
                }
                TextField("", text: $mySubstring) // <-- should use Text(mySubstring)
                    .frame(width: 150.0, height: 20.0)
            }
            .frame(width: 400.0, height: 200.0)
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=1502026&appid=xxxxx")!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let theData = data {
                let info = String(data: theData, encoding: .utf8)!
                let index = info.index(info.startIndex, offsetBy: 16)
                let endindex = info.index(info.startIndex, offsetBy: 22)
                self.mySubstring = String(info[index...endindex])
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
}
```